# How to execute cmd line of psexec and log to text file in a single line using JAVA?

Tags: java, cmd

I am trying to execute the following line in java(with **escaped characters**):

```
"psexec -i -d \\\\computerName -u user -p pass calc 2>  
 somePath\\psexecOut.txt"
```

I use the following method to execute cmd lines:

```
private static String executeCommand(String command) {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    System.out.println("command is = \n"+command);
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader =
                           new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                       String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();

}
```

The line is executed and calc is starting , but the log part doesn't work. The log file `psexecOut.txt` is not created.

When I run the command normally (without excaped characters) in cmd it runs fine and the log file is created, but using java it doesn't create the log file.

I suspect that `>` needs to be escaped but as I read it's already escaped as it is.

**How can I execute the psexec with log to text file in a single cmd line using java like I can do manually in windows console ?**

Comment: Have you tried putting `cmd.exe /C ` at the beginning of the command? It is cmd.exe that interprets the `>` redirection.

Comment: Wow thanks man. That did the trick! You're awsome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
As lit suggested in the comments: `cmd.exe /c` works.

So the corrected method is:

```
private static String executeCommand(String command) {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    System.out.println("command is = \n"+command);
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c "+command); // <-correction done here
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader =
                           new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                       String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting cmd.exe /C at the beginning of the command? It is cmd.exe that interprets the > redirection.

```
"cmd.exe /C psexec -i -d \\\\computerName -u user -p pass calc 2> somePath\\psexecOut.txt"
```